# What is the minimum PHP version for using the static:: keyword?

Tags: php, static

When using something like

```php
class MyClass
{
    public static function myFunction()
    {
        static::myOtherFunction();
    }

    private static function myOtherFunction()
    {
        …
    }
}
```

the PHP parser will complain

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC in ….php on line …
```

in older PHP versions. I couldn't find a reference though, what the minimum PHP version would be to use the `static` keyword like that.

Comment: Late Static Bindings, 5.3, http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the newest PHP version? Much more powerfull & supported.

Comment: Please show the actual code displaying this error. Being on < 5.3 with that code would not give that error.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are using a version of PHP that is older than PHP 5.3, which means you can't use late static bindings as it doesn't recognize static::myOtherFunction().

Answer (score 1):

It's 5.3.0

`As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value cannot be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).`

via http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php